# Blender Out Of Memory and Crashing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, memory-management

I'm trying to create a mountain scene in Blender and when i started adding some bump mapping blender started absolutely eating up RAM (quickly shooting up to the 8GB I have) and then running out of memory. Even after I removed the nodes added it now quickly runs up to 8GB and then crashes... What do I do, is my prject broken?

http://www.mediafire.com/file/yrtzn40tac767na/Mountain.blend

Comment: I can at least open the file without any problems. Do you have to do something to trigger it?